# BigQuery - Policy Tags - Shared attribute

Tags: google-bigquery

I know we can't add more attributes than just name and description, hence my approach to tags might be incorrect and I would like to know if this is right.

I'm planning on creating multiple taxonomies like this:

- master data
- primary contact data
- secondary contact data

Each taxonomy will then have a similar second level (High, Medium, Low) in terms of risk, and third level are fields.

Would I still be able to get information about all columns on a specific second level? For example, all columns that are "High"?

Even when applying data masking or column-level access, I would like to use the sensitivity level. How do I plan this part?

-- edit
Perhaps the hierarchy should be different? Something like this:

- high

  - master data
  - primary contact data
- medium

  - master data
  - primary contact data
- low

  - master data
  - primary contact data

Comment: Hi @Moseleyi, could you please refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-data-masking-intro#data_masking_example_with_output) and let me know if this is helpful to you?

Comment: Hi @Moseleyi, Could you confirm if the above comment helped you or not ?

Comment: Not really. I've read the whole documentation multiple times. This is more of a best practice question for somebody who used it with a big project